# Fade in and out complex GameObject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, fadein, fadeout, effects

I am trying to create a 3D model viewer where the user can choose a model and see it. I want to add some fade in and out effect when the user selects a model.

I know I need to set the material to transparent and change the alpha value, but it destroys my model (it looks horrible). Is there another way to achieve this effect without messing with the material?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try by placing a sprite/plane GameObject in foreground and apply fading to it other than the actual 3D model? Just a possible alternative solution, not an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @Hristo it doesn't help, the solution there is to change the material to transparent, I can't do it

Comment: @ZzAtomiic like a screen that hides the object? it is an option but I am still going to search the solution

Comment: @user9977758 Yes, something like a loading screen/spash screen sounds meaningful.

Comment: @Programmer how is it duplicate¿ I have stated I can't use transparent material